# How do you use the constructor in Angular to set the value of a property?

Tags: angular

I'm having trouble setting the value of a property by calling a function.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    @Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root'
    })
export class PeopleService {

givenProperty: string = "GivenString";

givenFunction() {
    this.givenProperty = "NewGivenString";
    var one = 1;
    if (one == 1) {
    return this.givenProperty;
      }
   }
}

Why is the `givenProperty` in the `givenFunction` not in scope? How can I make it in scope so that I can change it and use it again outside the function?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I unintentionally left the call to the function out of the constructor. In fact, I left the constructor out entirely. Once I added it to the constructor, it worked as I expected.

```
constructor() {
     this.givenProperty = this.givenFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular 2.0 is using new concepts instead of $scope. HTML elements already have an easily bindable interface in events, attributes, and properties. For your property `GivenProperty` you need to use it in HTML template to see results.

Also, Angular 2 doesn't share data between components as AngularJS. It binds data by using it inside the template and passing up events to other components.

Check these links:
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Comment: Thanks @ali-ben-messaoud! I am going to spend the entire day going through this tutorial. I looks like the answer I need is in there. I just need to understand it better.